# How to set ChartJS x-axis title

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

We are using Chartjs to plot the charts ,However there is no to give the x-axis titles,There is a solution for y-Axis title in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913967/how-to-set-chartjs-y-axis-title/31918380?noredirect=1#comment57102473_31918380) , But for x-Axis I could add the x axis name but could not create the space below the chart to properly place it , using y as this.chart.height overlapped the text with x axis title.

I have looked the chartjs v2.0 but it also does not have support for x-Axis title.

Comment: In v.2 it is possible, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36954319/858981

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We set the height of the chart depending on how much height we want for the x axis label and then write in that space.

We don't have to do anything in the `draw` override because the canvas clearing too happens based on the height (that we adjusted)

**Preview**

[image]

---

**Script**

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt",
    initialize: function (data) {
        this.chart.height -= 30;

        Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.save();
        // text alignment and color
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
        ctx.fillStyle = this.options.scaleFontColor;
        // position
        var x = this.chart.width / 2;
        var y = this.chart.height + 15 + 5;
        // change origin
        ctx.translate(x, y)
        ctx.fillText("My x axis label", 0, 0);
        ctx.restore();
    }
});
```

and then

```
...
new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ct2h2wde/

Comment: Need to give you reddit gold on this!