# How to add axis titles in chart.js charts

Tags: javascript, chart.js

is there a way I can add x and y axis titles on chart.js charts? I could not find a specific option for axis titles in the documentation...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Y-title: see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913967/how-to-set-chartjs-y-axis-title/31918380?noredirect=1#comment57102473_31918380)
X-title: see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913967/how-to-set-chartjs-y-axis-title/31918380?noredirect=1#comment57102473_31918380)

**Original response**

From the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-example-usage):

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);

var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        }
    ]
};
```

Where `labels` = x-axis labels

And for the Y-axis, with a [little SO search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371867/chart-js-formatting-y-axis):

```
var options = {   
    scaleLabel: function (valuePayload) {
        // Do something with valuePayload.value
        return valuePayload.value;
    }
};

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
```

Comment: Hi - sorry, i realized as I read your answer that i meant axis TITLES, not labels...

Comment: Why don't you add the title directly in the html code ?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715163/how-to-set-chartjs-x-axis-title