# How to change the Y-Axis to show $ in graph

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, charts, chart.js

I want to see dollar sign along with the Y-Axis scale data. I am using ChartJS Version 2.1.0 for rendering graph. I looked into this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913967/how-to-set-chartjs-y-axis-title) but I could not understand. I know I need to change my **ScaleLabel** but I am not able to do so. Kindly guide me. so scale `2000 should show as $2000`
Below is what I have till now.

```
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {
  var firstSubViewModel = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#myChart-template').html()),
    render: function() {
      $(this.el).html(this.template());
      var ctx = $(this.el).find('#lineChart')[0];
      var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
          datasets: {
            label: "This Year",
            data: this.model.attributes.incThisYear
          }
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      });
    },
    initialize: function() {
      this.render();
    }
  });
  return firstSubViewModel;
});
```

**Image:**

[image]

**EDIT**

My options looks like this now:

```
  options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{

              scaleLabel: function (incValue){ return '$ '+ incValue.value; }
            }]
          }
        }
```

Comment: Would you try this the following?

scaleLabel: function (incValue){
 return '$ '+ incValue.value;
}

Comment: I added the new code. But it has no effect at all. I have added the new code snippet. Please guide me. Thanks!

Comment: Try to add scaleLabel in the same level as scales. Like options: {
                   scaleLabel: function (incValue){ return '$ '+ incValue.value; }
                }

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to add the following to the options:

```
scaleLabel: function (incValue){ return '$ '+ incValue.value; }
```

It is working in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/uLUAT/145/)

Comment: Thanks for the help. But scaleLabel is not showing any effect on my graph while rendering. I dont know what's the issue. I will try to add the the way `options` has been added in fiddle example.

Comment: I figured out the issue. In Version 2.0 + we need to use `ticks` .