# How to set X-axis and Y-axis title in a chart in ionic framework?

Tags: user-interface, ionic-framework

This is the code that i have used

for inserting the chart
and this is the controller that i have used

```
.controller('ExampleCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
    $scope.data = [
        [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    ];
})
```

someone please do help me with this issue..!!!

Comment: Would this be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913967/how-to-set-chartjs-y-axis-title

Comment: I have seen this but how can i use this code it in ionic framework?